# Bar Plot alignment issue in R

Tags: r, bar-chart

The given data frame consist of various rows some of sample are containing 3 columns

```
    df1 <- data.frame( income = c(>20K, <=20K, >20K, <=20K),
              country name = c(Cuba, Cuba, USA, USA),
               count = c(10, 12, 21, 27)
```

I want to plot barplot with country name filled by income. Not get in correct result

Here my code

```
          ggplot(df2, aes(x = region)) + 
          geom_bar(aes(fill = income), position = "fill")
```

Please help!!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues here:

1. Your sample data frame was called `df1`, but the `ggplot` call had `df2` as the data argument.
2. The strings in `df1` weren't wrapped in quotes
3. `df1` was missing a closing parenthesis.
4. `df1` also had an illegal column name, `country name`, which wasn't wrapped in quotes.
5. There was no column called `region` in your data frame, yet that's what you used in your ggplot call.
6. You used `geom_bar` which by default counts the entries in your data frame rather than plotting the actual counts you wanted, so you should have specified `count` for the y axis and made this a `geom_col`
7. I'm not sure what `position = "fill"` is doing here.

Anyway, if you fix all that, it seems to work OK.

```r
df1 <- data.frame( income = c(">20K", "<=20K", ">20K", "<=20K"),
                   region = c("Cuba", "Cuba", "USA", "USA"),
                   count  = c(10, 12, 21, 27))
    
ggplot(df1, aes(x = region, y = count)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = income))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Allan Cameron